# Converting a .NET object to (byte*)

Tags: .net, casting

Is there a way to cast a `System.Object` to `byte*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
byte[] b = (byte[]) myobj;
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like...

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(1024);

Object1 blah = new Object1("Hello");

bf.Serialize(ms, blah);
byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to Jon Skeet](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/269250-casting-object-byte-array), it is possible through just casting it to a byte array.

Comment: I need cast to unsafe pointer. I ve made a workaround. Passing int through function. I can easily convert byte* to int and int to byte*.
But still the question is here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution:

```
(byte*)(int)someObject
```

Comment: What if someObject is larger than an int?

Comment: Doesn't work in 64-bit mode.  A pointer is larger than an int.